# SWT Rendering small Fonts

Tags: eclipse, fonts, swt, rendering, antialiasing

I am currently trying to render small fonts (Tahoma regular 8) using the SWT GC on Windows 7. My problem is, that the last two digits are always very close to each other:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iachelini.de](http://www.iachelini.de/538.png))</sub>

I noticed the same effect when drawing beveled strings:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iachelini.de](http://www.iachelini.de/1772.png))</sub>

According to the javadoc the setAntialias method only relates to non-font drawings. I wonder what other things I could do. To turn Clear-Type off is -unfortunately- no option.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `GC#setTextAntialias`?

Comment: Thanks. How could I overlook this. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

I have also win7 and turning off the antialiasing by `setAntialiasing(SWT.OFF)` is working for me in SWT examples..

[image: Antialias SWT.OFF]

[image: Antialias SWT.ON]

Comment: Thanks, but the setAntialiasing is for non-text drawing only, which has to be off in my case.